# Fixing mojibake for email

Tags: email, encoding, mojibake

My application for macOS archives emails from email clients and IMAP accounts. One user got an email from a Windows user and archived the email from Mail. My app reads the data directly from the hard disk.

The user has an email with some a nice mojibake:

[image]

I can identify a few of the characters:

â€° → ä
Â¸ → ü

But I can't figure out whhat the original encoding is. I made myself an encoding table for the characters "ö  ä  ü  ß" and my data is not in that table:

[image]

Code:

```
dim theLeft as string = "ö  ä  ü  ß"
for currentEncoding as integer = 0 to Encodings.Count - 1
  
  dim EncodingInternetName as String = Encodings.Item(currentEncoding).internetName
  
  if EncodingInternetName.IndexOf("iso") = -1 and EncodingInternetName.IndexOf("windows") = -1 then Continue
  dim newString as string = DefineEncoding(theLeft, Encodings.Item(currentEncoding))  '<---convert
  newString = ConvertEncoding(newString, Encodings.UTF8)
  Result.Add(EncodingInternetName + " " + newString)
  
next
```

Does anyone have an idea what encoding was used for the Mojibake?

Comment: You face a **double** [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'ö ä ü ß'.encode( 'cp1252').decode( 'mac-roman').encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `Ë† â€° Â¸ ï¬‚` and vice versa: `'Ë† â€° Â¸ ï¬‚'.encode( 'cp1252').decode( 'utf-8').encode( 'mac-roman').decode( 'cp1252')` -> `ö ä ü ß` …

Comment: Thanks, I was able to adapt that to my language.

Answer (score 0):

```
dim theString as String = "Ë† â€° Â¸ ï¬‚"
theString = theString.ConvertEncoding(Encodings.WindowsANSI)
theString = theString.DefineEncoding(Encodings.UTF8)
theString = theString.ConvertEncoding(Encodings.MacRoman)
theString = theString.DefineEncoding(Encodings.WindowsANSI)
theString = theString.ConvertEncoding(Encodings.UTF8)
```